# Creating domain name mapping on GCP is stuck at "waiting for certificate provisioning"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns

This may be a very simple thing, but I am pretty new to GCP and don't really understand how all this stuff works so please bear with me.

I am trying to host a static site with GCP. My site is built with Jekyll and I am using GCP containers to deploy it. I got that part working.

I then wanted to give it a human-friendly URL. I bought one using the GCP console and then went to create a domain name mapping. So far I have been waiting for a couple of days. I read on some other similar posts that canceling and restarting the mapping process helped with the issue, but I've tried 3 times so far waiting ~24 hours between each, and no luck still.

It tells me that I need to configure the DNS records with my domain host, but if I understand it correctly GCP is my domain host. I have also followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/records) and still no luck.

Am I doing something wrong or perhaps I am missing something here?

Note: I have DNSSEC on, maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: *GCP is my domain host.* No, this depends with which provider you got your domain like Google domains, Godday, etc. Then, if you're using Cloud DNS I'd ask, have you configured your nameservers to use the Cloud DNS services?

Comment: Hmm, if I check in the Cloud Domains in my GCP console, under the DNS column it says Cloud DNS, does that not mean GCP is my domain host? For your second question, I am not sure, to be honest, could you suggest where I might check that?

Comment: What is the domain name?

Comment: Thanks for the details @djvaroli, if you could share the domain we can check the DNS records as John mentioned